# $p$ prime. Is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]{p})/\mathbb Q$ Galois?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

- $p$ prime. When is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]{p})/\mathbb Q$ Galois?
- Find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[p]{p}$
- Let $L$ be a splitting field of $\sqrt[p]{p}$ over $\mathbb Q$. Find $[L:\mathbb Q]$

---

My approach:

Since $\mathbb Q$ is perfect we only need the field extension to be normal. That is the case iff it is the splitting field of a set of polynomials.

So that definitely is the case if $\mathbb Q$ contains all solutions of $x^p-p=0$ (then it would be the splitting field of $x^p-p$). That is the case iff $p \leq 2$ since otherwise we get complex numbers that are not in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]{p})$.

The other implication should follow this way: $x^p-p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$ via Eisenstein, hence also irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$. Therefore it is the minimalpolynomial of $\sqrt[p]{p}$. Thus, if $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]{p})/\mathbb Q$ would be normal, so $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]{p})$ is a splitting field of a set of polynomials, one of these polynomials, let's call it $f$, must satisfy $x^p-p \,\,|\,\,f$. But then $\mathbb Q$ would contain all solutions for $x^p-p=0$.

Is this correct?

Second and third part:

$x^p-p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$ via Eisenstein, hence also irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$, therefore it is the minimal polynomial and therefore $[L:\mathbb Q] = p$.

---

The solutions say it's wrong but I cannot spot the mistake...

Comment: $x^p-p$ doesn't have to divide $f$. (For $p\ge 3$) it is not Galois because the (Eisenstein) minimal polynomial $x^p-p$ of one of its elements doesn't split completely (it has some non-real roots).

Comment: Thanks. But why can't it be the splitting field for a set of different polynomials than $x^p-p$?